# Looking for a little assistance working with Powershell and JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I have next to zero programming experience but I've done a tiny bit of work with with Powershell so I've picked this for a little project I'm working on. I'm trying to pull some information from JSON and so far have been able to figure it out as I go but the result is formatted strangely which is throwing me for a loop. Here's a snippet of the JSON result:

```
 "data":  {
     "reviews":  [
         {
          "available_at":  "2021-06-18T12:00:00.000000Z",
          "subject_ids":  [
               7572,
               3428,
               759,
               732,
               712,
               718,
               731
              ]
         },
         {
          "available_at":  "2021-06-18T22:00:00.000000Z",
          "subject_ids":  [
               730,
               710,
               854,
               1029,
               2938,
               736,
               734
              ]
         },
         {
          "available_at":  "2021-06-19T03:00:00.000000Z",
          "subject_ids":  [
               3493,
               3086,
               3091,
               2847
              ]
         }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get a count of  each set of data.reviews.subject_ids.  By using `($summary.data.reviews.subject_ids | Measure-Object).count` I get a result of 18, which is to be expected, since there are 18 subject_ids. I only want the count of the first group of 7 though and I can't figure out how to get this from the first set but not the second, third etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Your example json has a ```{``` missing before the ```"data": {```, btw...

Comment: Just for context: The unstated premise of your question is that the input JSON text was converted to a (`[pscustomobject]`) object graph via the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet, which then allows the use of dot notation (property access; e.g.,`$fromJson.foo.bar`) and indexing (array-element access; e.g. `$fromJson.foo.bar[0]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, you're using this syntax `$summary.data.reviews.subject_ids`, which says give me all of the `subject_ids` of all `reviews` inside of `summary.data`.

The item you want though is the first member of the array of reviews.  We can get that by using indexing notation like this,`$summary.data.reviews[0]`, which says "give me the first item in `reviews`".

PowerShell starts counting from 0, like a lot of programming languages, so that's why we say `0` to mean the first one in the list.

You can then `dereference` the specific fields you want, just like before, with this syntax `$summary.data.reviews[0].subject_ids`.

Answer (score 3):

`$summary.data.reviews` is an array of 3 children (i.e. the `available_at` and `subject_ids` blocks).

At the moment you're counting the number of items in the `subject_ids` property for all 3 children.

If you want to just select the first one you can use:

`$summary.data.reviews[0]`

Note that arrays are zero-indexed in PowerShell so the first index is `[0]`, the second is `[1]` and the Nth is `[N-1]`.

Your code then becomes:

```
($summary.data.reviews[0].subject_ids | Measure-Object).Count
#7
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the position of the array you want to count.

From [about Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#reading-an-array):

> You can refer to the elements in an array by using an index, beginning at position 0. Enclose the index number in brackets.

```
PS /> $json.data.reviews

available_at                subject_ids              
------------                -----------              
2021-06-18T12:00:00.000000Z {7572, 3428, 759, 732...}
2021-06-18T22:00:00.000000Z {730, 710, 854, 1029...} 
2021-06-19T03:00:00.000000Z {3493, 3086, 3091, 2847} 

PS /> $json.data.reviews.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name       BaseType
-------- -------- ----       --------
True     True     Object[]   System.Array

PS /> $json.data.reviews

available_at                subject_ids              
------------                -----------              
2021-06-18T12:00:00.000000Z {7572, 3428, 759, 732...}
2021-06-18T22:00:00.000000Z {730, 710, 854, 1029...} 
2021-06-19T03:00:00.000000Z {3493, 3086, 3091, 2847} 

PS /> $json.data.reviews[0]

available_at                subject_ids              
------------                -----------              
2021-06-18T12:00:00.000000Z {7572, 3428, 759, 732...}

PS /> $json.data.reviews[0].subject_ids.Count
7
```

If you want to iterate over all elements and get their count you can do like this:

```
$i=1;foreach($object in $json.data.reviews)
{
    "- Group $i has {0}" -f $object.subject_ids.count
    $i++
}
```

Which yields:

```
- Group 1 has 7
- Group 2 has 7
- Group 3 has 4
```